# XDG_DATA_DIRS contains duplicate paths; How to fix?

Tags: mime-types

I'm running Arch Linux and KDE and curious to learn about mime type file associations.

While investigating my system I noticed this issue:

```
$ echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/share:/usr/share:/usr/local/share
```

Notice that the path `/usr/share` is duplicated. I'd like to know how to troubleshoot that and how to resolve it.

Furthermore, my system does not have an `/usr/local/share/applications/`
Can that path be removed from the`$XDG_DATA_DIRS` env var? If so, how?

I believe that the end result should be:

```
$ echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/share
```

Here is some troubleshooting info. I don't see those paths when running as root. This produces no std out:

```
# echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

In my normal user account on my machine, the following command produces no standard output and a return value of `1`:

```
$ grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS /etc/profile.d/
```

This search finds no matches except within binary file places.sqlite (within Firefox profile):

```
find /home/myuser -mount -type f -exec grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS= {} +
```

This also produces no standard output:

```
grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS /etc/
```

So far, the only match I have found is this:

```
# grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS= /usr
/usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/prefix.sh.cmake:export XDG_DATA_DIRS=@KDE_INSTALL_FULL_DATADIR@:${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/}
```

So...

```
pacman -F /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/prefix.sh.cmake
usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/prefix.sh.cmake is owned by extra/extra-cmake-modules 5.66.0-1
```

Arch Linux - extra-cmake-modules 5.66.0-1 (any) https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/extra-cmake-modules/

I hope that package is not responsible for screwing up my mime type associations...

In a new user account on a clean Arch install on another device, the following three commands produce no standard output:

```
echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS /etc/profile.d/
grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS= /usr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Furthermore, my system does not have an /usr/local/share/applications/
>   Can that path be removed from the $XDG_DATA_DIRS env var

`/usr/local/share/applications` is not in the `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` values you pasted so no need to remove the non-existent

If you
    grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS /usr

and you will see many occurrences of XDG_DATA_DIRS.

> I hope that package is not responsible for screwing up my mime type associations...

No, it doesn't screw up any thing. It just searches those directories as well

> In a new user account on a clean Arch install on another device, the
>   following three commands produce no standard output

Exactly, you get different values in different systems. It's those packages that you install and the env variables that are defined for that specific user, which would define the directories which will be searched for data files. If the same value is defined twice, then it would show up twice. There is nothing strange about having that because sometimes packages don't coordinate together. `grep` `/usr/`, `/opt` and `$HOME` and you will find the culprit somewhere for sure. If not `grep /` ;)

Comment: I used `grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS= /usr` because I was searching for an assignment. Files that simplly read, but do not set, the value should not be of interest. Furthermore, I did search all of `/usr` and `/home` and I did not find the culprit.

Comment: > "No, it doesn't screw any thing. It just searches those directories as well."

Notice the assignment and export. That's the only file I find doing assignment and export to XDG_DATA_DIRS.

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica: grep -r XDG_DATA_DIRS / and paste it in a gist e.g if you still need help

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `zsh` shell, you can add to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
typeset -UT XDG_DATA_DIRS xdg_data_dirs
```

Then the `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` scalar variable will be `T`ied to the `$xdg_data_dirs` which makes it a lot easier to manipulate and the elements are made `U`nique with `-U`.

Then to remove the non-existing components, you can add:

```
xdg_data_dirs=($^xdg_data_dirs(N-/))
```

Which would remove components that are not actual directories (`/`, after symlink resolution (`-`))

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates and non-existing directories in bash :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share:/usr/share:/usr/local/share
IFS=: read -ra xdg_data_dirs <<< "$XDG_DATA_DIRS"
declare -p xdg_data_dirs
for d in "${xdg_data_dirs[@]}"; do
    test -d "$d" || continue
    [[ :$result: != *:$d:* ]] || continue
    result+="${result+:}$d"
done
XDG_DATA_DIRS=$result
```

Have you searched in your home directory ?

Comment: I just did that and added the result (no matches) to the question.

Comment: 'export XDG_DATA_DIRS=$result' results in a new value while the script is running, but the existing export value (with the duplicates) remains in effect as soon as the script terminates.

Answer (score 0):

> While investigating my system I noticed this issue:
>
> ```
> $ echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS  
> /usr/share:/usr/share:/usr/local/share
> ```
>
> Notice that the path /usr/share is duplicated. I'd like to know how to troubleshoot that and how to resolve it. My system does not have an `/usr/local/share/applications/`

This is the only foolproof solution I found:

```
unset XDG_DATA_DIRS
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share
```

I put those commands in my `~/.bashrc` file

Answer (score 0):

Check /usr/bin/x-session-manager and /usr/bin/startxfce4
both of these duplicate /usr/share in XDG_DATA_DIRS.

Comment: Could you expand on this a little to explain how to fix things, since that’s what the question is asking?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu it was stored in `~/.xsessionrc`